# How to avoid joining subclass when query superclass in the Hibernate inheritance with joined strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

There are 3 Class:

```
 @Entity
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Animal extends BaseEntity {
        String eye;
        public String getEye() {
            return eye;
        }
        public void setEye(String eye) {
            this.eye = eye;
        }
    }

    @Entity
    public class Cat extends Animal {
        String catName;
        public String getCatName() {
            return catName;
        }
        public void setCatName(String catName) {
            this.catName = catName;
        }
    }
    @Entity
    public class Dog extends Animal {
        String dogName;
        public String getDogName() {
            return dogName;
        }
        public void setDogName(String dogName) {
            this.dogName = dogName;
        }
    }
```

When query Animal, Hibernate generate SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
  animal0_.id AS id1_7_0_,
  animal0_.eye AS eye2_7_0_,
  animal0_1_.catName AS catName1_8_0_,
  animal0_2_.dogName AS dogName1_9_0_,
  CASE
    WHEN animal0_1_.id IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 1 
    WHEN animal0_2_.id IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 2 
    WHEN animal0_.id IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 0 
  END AS clazz_0_ 
FROM
  Animal animal0_ 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Cat animal0_1_ 
    ON animal0_.id = animal0_1_.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Dog animal0_2_ 
    ON animal0_.id = animal0_2_.id 
WHERE animal0_.id = ?
```

just like the [Hibernate_User_Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table) said.

so,the question is: how to avoid joining subclass when query superclass ?
mostly, only the properties in superclass is need —— just ignore its subclass!

( Imaging that Animal has lots of subclass like Bird,Pig,Fish,Insect... in that case, the Animal-query will have performance problem. )

Comment: Select only the properties you need, instead of selecting the whole entity.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a solution for this case still in Hibernate 6. The only 'solution' that I found is to only select specific columns:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Animal> query = builder.createQuery(Animal.class);
Root<Animal> animal = query.from(Animal.class);
query.multiselect(animal.get("eye"));
List<Animal> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

It stills makes all this annoying left outer joins but it returns only the specified columns.